# Zend Lucene MoreLikeThis

Tags: zend-framework, search, lucene, morelikethis

I'm using Zend_Search_Lucene for my search engine. Sadly it is missing an implementation of the MorelikeThis methods which can find similar documents in the index.

Has anybody come across a decent Zend port of this function?

I found a [drupal module](http://drupal.org/project/luceneapi_morelikethis) but have no idea if this can be used with Zend without some serious hacking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ZF guys did a great job with Zend_Search_Lucene, but it just isn't as robust as [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).  I would highly recommend using either one of those, as they would give you the [MoreLikeThis](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis) functionality that you are looking for, in addition to so many more features.

If you Google 'solr vs sphinx' you'll find several articles comparing the two.

Both search engines have PHP interfaces, so that makes integration easy. https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.search.php

Comment: +1 for an actual answer at long last. :) I did look at solr and came to the conclusion it would be the best way forward. I left this project in January, so maybe the current team will stumble upon this question and come to the same conclusion :)

Comment: Given one uses a shared hosting env where pure php is the only options to go - would Solr or Sphinx be usable there?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Both require more than just PHP.

Answer (score 2):

[Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) is accesible from a rest API which allows you to use it with any language. It's also owned by the people who own Lucene, so you are more likely to get updates and/or patches such as this in a timely manner. For example we have a patch for field collapsing that works in 1.4, that functionality is not slated until version 4.0, 3.0 was just released in March if that gives you any idea about how easy it is to get access to new features in Lucene.